# Nodejs Stream User's Webcam

Tags: node.js, webrtc, peerjs

I want to make an Web app which streams user's webcam which broadcast to viewers
like one to many!

I know `getuserMedia()` will help me to get user's webcam. now how to stream this data with audio.

I google about this i get few result like using `WebRTC` and `peerjs` can do this but I need some kick-start guide like some code or documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try [easyrtc](/questions/tagged/easyrtc), is a node.js library for giving WebRTC support to your apps. Is open source and packs some cool demos for you to start making awesome stuff.